# Rust lifetime mismatch - 'a does not necessarily outlive lifetime as defined here

Tags: rust

I'm running into lifetime issues when trying to move borrowed data between structs. At a high level I'd like to do something like:

- read a yml file into a string buffer
- deserialize that into a struct using `from_str`
- create a different struct from that same borrowed data
- write that out to a file

Here's a sample implementation of what I built that gives the lifetime error:

[Rust playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=383c28645fcdb91b26b05d723e1a27e2)

```rust
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug, Serialize)]
pub struct Foo<'a> {
  name: &'a str
}

impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    
    pub fn new(name: &'a str) -> Self {
        Self { name }
    }
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug, Serialize)]
pub struct Bar<'a> {
  name: &'a str
}

impl<'a> Bar<'a> {
    
    pub fn new(name: &'a str) -> Self {
        Self { name }
    }
}


pub trait Visitor {
    type Value;
    fn visit_table_borrowed<'a>(&mut self, t: &'a Foo<'a>) {
        let _ = t;
    }
}

pub trait DataBorrowed {
    fn accept<V: Visitor>(&self, visitor: &mut V);
}

impl<'a> DataBorrowed for Foo<'a> {
    fn accept<V: Visitor>(&self, visitor: &mut V) {
        visitor.visit_table_borrowed(self)
    }
}


impl<'a> Visitor for Bar<'a> {
    type Value = Bar<'a>;
    fn visit_table_borrowed(&mut self, t: &'a Foo<'a>) {
       self.name = t.name;
    }
}

impl<'a> From<Foo<'a>> for Bar<'a> {
    fn from(dt: Foo<'a>) -> Self {
        let mut table = Bar::new("bar");
        dt.accept(&mut table);
        table
    }
}

fn main() {
    let f = Foo::new("foo");
    let b: Bar = Bar::from(f);
    
}
```

The error:

```
error[E0308]: method not compatible with trait
  --> src/main.rs:49:5
   |
49 |     fn visit_table_borrowed(&mut self, t: &'a Foo<'a>) {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ lifetime mismatch
   |
   = note: expected signature `fn(&mut Bar<'a>, &'a Foo<'a>)`
              found signature `fn(&mut Bar<'a>, &'a Foo<'a>)`
note: the lifetime `'a` as defined here...
  --> src/main.rs:49:5
   |
49 |     fn visit_table_borrowed(&mut self, t: &'a Foo<'a>) {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: ...does not necessarily outlive the lifetime `'a` as defined here
  --> src/main.rs:47:6
   |
47 | impl<'a> Visitor for Bar<'a> {
   |      ^^

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem with your code is that your trait definition and the actual implementation don't match in their signature, one method does have a lifetime parameter, the other doesn't, this is what the compiler complains about.
To fix this you can just double check that both methods have the same signature (I personally always copy & paste the signature over from the trait's definition or let the LSP server do that for me).

Then there is the problem that `&'a Foo<'a>` really is a code smell more often than not, it's virtually never the actual lifetime and ok in only a few more cases. Unless you know what you're doing you should always start with a different lifetime per lifetime hole, that way the compiler can tell you exactly what it thinks how those lifetimes relate.

You don't actually want your borrows to be limited by the reference to the `Foo`, after all you want to move the reference from it and use that longer lifetime, but that's impossible if you artificially force `'a` and `'b` of `&'a Foo<'b>` to be the same by reusing `'a` for the inner lifetime.
To fix this replace `&'a Foo<'a>` with `&Foo<'a>` everywhere (the outer lifetime can be elided in all places you used it)

The third problem is that your trait definitions don't allow for your requirements, you can't have a function be generic over a lifetime and at the same time fix that same lifetime to some lifetime from the implementation.
To fix it change `Visitor` and `DataBorrowed` to accept a lifetime parameter:

```rust
pub trait Visitor<'a> {
    type Value;
    fn visit_table_borrowed(&mut self, t: &Foo<'a>) {
        let _ = t;
    }
}

pub trait DataBorrowed<'a> {
    fn accept<V: Visitor<'a>>(&self, visitor: &mut V);
}
```

Here is a complete version with all three problems fixed:

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug, Serialize)]
pub struct Foo<'a> {
    name: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    pub fn new(name: &'a str) -> Self {
        Self { name }
    }
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug, Serialize)]
pub struct Bar<'a> {
    name: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> Bar<'a> {
    pub fn new(name: &'a str) -> Self {
        Self { name }
    }
}

pub trait Visitor<'a> {
    type Value;
    fn visit_table_borrowed(&mut self, t: &Foo<'a>) {
        let _ = t;
    }
}

pub trait DataBorrowed<'a> {
    fn accept<V: Visitor<'a>>(&self, visitor: &mut V);
}

impl<'a> DataBorrowed<'a> for Foo<'a> {
    fn accept<V: Visitor<'a>>(&self, visitor: &mut V) {
        visitor.visit_table_borrowed(self)
    }
}

impl<'a> Visitor<'a> for Bar<'a> {
    type Value = Bar<'a>;
    fn visit_table_borrowed(&mut self, t: &Foo<'a>) {
        self.name = t.name;
    }
}

impl<'a> From<Foo<'a>> for Bar<'a> {
    fn from(dt: Foo<'a>) -> Self {
        let mut table = Bar::new("bar");
        dt.accept(&mut table);
        table
    }
}

fn main() {
    let f = Foo::new("foo");
    let b: Bar = Bar::from(f);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation! I actually had no idea about the `&'a Foo<'a>` issue so you saved me several hours of compiler issues in addition to solving the problem I immediately had.